# Does displacement current exist after the capacitor gets fully charged?

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, capacitance, maxwell-equations

The displacement current is due to changing electric field. Since, after the capacitor gets fully charged there is no changing electric field there is no displacement current.(capacitor connected to a DC voltage input) This is my understanding. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No it is other way around. The displacement current epistemic concept was introduced by Maxwell to explain how the electric field is created between the capacitor's plates. Thus, the electric field is due the displacement current and not the other way around according to Maxwell.

Comment: Also there is note in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#:~:text=Maxwell's%20emphasis%20on%20polarization%20diverted,in%20an%20electric%20capacitor%20circuit. that Maxwell conceived the idea of the displacement current in order to explain the conservation of charge in an electric capacitor circuit. Which displacement current  must be therefore always present in order the charge to be maintained on the capacitor according to this idea of Maxwell.

Answer (score 1):

> after the capacitor gets fully charged there is no changing electric field there is no displacement current.

Correct.

Displacement current is present if and only if there is a change in the electric field with time. A capacitor which is in a steady state, (i.e. the voltage between the plates is constant with time) has no displacement current.

Comment: again with a correct answer in the face of incorrect answers. Thank you, hopefully the OP is not confused by the false statements in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Because a capacitor both real and ideal take infinite time to charge , the equation for charging is '$Q = Q_0 (1 - e^{\frac{-t}{CR}}) $'. Clearly due to the exponential function charging will take infinite time and till that time current keeps on flowing at a reducing magnitude and hence a displacement current exists till inifinite time.

However, as after 4 time constants $CR$ the capacitor is nearly fully charged, the magnitude of current becomes negligible and even more so with passing time, this in turn renders the displacement current negligible and then unobservable.

Also, as satwik pasani says In a steady state there is neither conduction or displacement current. But I don't think you can possibly have a capacitor in a circuit I  steady state again because of infinite charging time.

Comment: Well, we don't have to be *that* critical. Most time constants are in the order of *milliseconds*, that is the capacitor is already charged 63% in a thousandth of a second. Even after just a few minutes, I think it's safe to say that the capacitor is fully charged and the current is $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I do say in my answer That it is practically negligible and unbservable, however since theoretically since it is there, we should not just skim it.

Comment: Isn't there a minus sign missing in the exponential in the equation for Q? As to the charging matter, this seems rather academic. Just disconnect the capacitor from the power source and it will be in a steady state.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I am corrcting it right away

Comment: @rijulgupta: theoretically, it may be there in a perfect vacuum and for a current made up of a continuously charged fluid, but after a relatively reasonable amount of time, the capacitor will be one or two electrons from being fully charged, and then there will be random time dependent effects that will swamp the time dependence due to the charging of the plates, like, say, stray electric fields due to the gas in the room and the like.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : what you say is possible both theoretically and experimentally, but what is your point ? Certainly one can not deny the fact that there will indeed be currents though unobservable !

Comment: @rijulgupta: no.  There will not be a current obeying $I = I_{0}e^{t/\tau}$ after a finite time.  Once $Q-CV = O(e)$, (and probably before then) the current in the system will be essentially a random walk more accurately represented as zero than as a decaying exponential.

Comment: At what point would you say that the decaying exponential function has done all it could do and now its just a 0, how many time constants, if you say n, then why not n+1 or n-1. I understand the existence of such a minute, unobservable, extremely negligible current is not at all useful but is there just the same. Like when you say diamond is forever, it will be there for generations, and you may say it is for forever sincd it has been here for far too long, but is undeniably converting into graphite at a very slow pace.

Comment: I t is quite easy to get a capacitor into a state in which it is neither charging nor discharging. Just open a switch connected to the capacitor. Infinite time is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Displacement Current actually does not exist, it is a theoretical misnomer. When we consider a Capacitor as a low Characteristic Impedance Transmission Line we can think of energy flow between the conductors (Parallel Plates) We see a TEM wave (ExH) moving at the speed of light for the medium.

What Maxwell thought of as Displacement current is the difference in time between the energy flowing from the right being different to that flowing from the left. Also as a changing magnetic field is orthogonal to the changing Electric field (in a relationship based up the Zo of the medium) and cannot "cause" the other. Similarly a changing E field cannot "cause" a H field. They are inextricably linked as a TEM wave for all mediums.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250306485_Travelling_at_the_Speed_of_Light

A charged Capacitor has the energy flowing from each end cancelling out (the H field) and thus no observed current flow. However when we apply a sine wave signal we have a constant difference in time between the energy flowing in each direction of the parallel plate Capacitor. (or any shape for that matter) The key is to know that a Capacitor is a Transmission Line. A transmission line has the ability to transfer energy from A to B.

Answer (score -2):

Displacement current is a concept invented by Maxwell to describe how an electric field is propagated across the parallel plates of a capacitor. During the charging period of the capacitor the displacement current across the plates of the capacitor equals always the conduction current on the lines of the capacitor's circuit.

However, there is an interesting argument, what happens after the capacitor ideally is fully charged without any charge leakage since then the displacement field between its plates is at its maximum with no any conduction current present in the capacitor circuit lines? How is then the electric field propagated across the capacitor's plates?

To go around this caveat we theoretically assume that the displacement current between the parallel plates of the capacitor is always present even after the capacitor is charged and responsible for the electric field between its plates. The value of the displacement current after the capacitor is charged ideally then we say equals the maximum value of the the conduction current during charge which actually is the value we get right on the start of the capacitor charging period (i.e charging current drops down to zero with time).

This theoretical assumption actually is helpful in cases of calculations of the capacitor's displacement field across its plates after it is charged interacting directly with other electric charges like for example, what happens when an electric current carrying wire is introduced inside the displacement electric field of a fully charged capacitor?

Also there is a note in Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#:~:text=Maxwell's%20emphasis%20on%20polarization%20diverted,in%20an%20electric%20capacitor%20circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#:%7E:text=Maxwell%27s%20emphasis%20on%20polarization%20diverted,in%20an%20electric%20capacitor%20circuit). that Maxwell conceived the idea of the displacement current in order to explain the conservation of charge in an electric capacitor circuit. Which displacement current must be therefore always present in order the charge to be maintained on the capacitor according to this idea of Maxwell.

Comment: " we theoretically assume that the displacement current between the parallel plates of the capacitor is always present even after the capacitor is charged" NO. displacement current is present only when the voltage in the capacitor is changing, not when the voltage is in a steady state.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Good luck in proving using solely Maxwell equations, that an electric field exists between the capacitor plates after they are fully charged.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Also there is a note in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#:~:text=Maxwell's%20emphasis%20on%20polarization%20diverted,in%20an%20electric%20capacitor%20circuit. that Maxwell conceived the idea of the displacement current in order to explain the conservation of charge in an electric capacitor circuit. Which displacement current must be therefore always present in order the charge to be maintained on the capacitor according to this idea of Maxwell.

Comment: No, displacement current is proportional to the time derivative of the electric field, that is, it is proportional to the rate of change of the field with time. When the field is not changing, there is no displacement current.  The electric field in a capacitor only changes when the capacitor is charging or discharging.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy That all you describe is true and I agree if the displacement current had an ontological value and not pure epistemic origin. The displacement current is a misnomer in order to save Ampere's law.

Comment: Something that can cause a magnetic field seems pretty real to me. But to each his/her own.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The problem is that in a vacuum a current cannot cause an electric field.

Comment: "The problem is that in a vacuum a current cannot cause an electric field"  Except that a displacement current in a vacuum can cause a magnetic field. If the displacement current varies, the magnetic field will vary. This will cause an electric field.

Comment: But the displacement current does not exist according to  your interpretation after the the vacuum capacitor is fully charged? So there is no changing magnetic field to create an electric field. So how then you explain the electric field in a vacuum between the plates of the capacitor  after the capacitor is charged using the displacement current theory of Maxwell? Or do you imply that there is no electric field after the capacitor is charged? How is the electric field maintained? Do you see now what the problem is? Maxwell thought the vacuum as another medium at that time  as a dielectric.

Comment: The electric field between charged plates in a vacuum, when there is no magnetic field, is due to the charge. $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$

Comment: This is for monopole electric field. The field on the capacitor is a dipole electric field that infers always to moving charges between the plates of the capacitor thus a current.

Comment: The modern explanation of how an electric dipole field can exist in a vacuum is the quantum zero field fluctuations of the vacuum with charges constantly popping in and out of existence creating the necessary corridor for the field to travel through empty space.

Comment: "Constantly moving charges" doe not constitute a current unless there is a net drift of those charges. Random motion without a net drift is not a current.